# facebook message posting on page timeline

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to show post text/message on facebook page timeline. But is does not appear on facebook page timeline.It appears on notification section.
Code runs successfully and i get 200 response (means text/message successfully posted on facebook page).I am using latest Facebook API version 2.3.

Source Code

```
<?php
session_start();
// added in v4.0.0
require_once 'autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' );
// login helper with redirect_uri
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost:8080/facebook_Login_Version_4/fbconfig.php' );
try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}
// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

        $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
        $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); // To Get Facebook full name
        $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');    // To Get Facebook email ID
    /* ---- Session Variables -----*/
        $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;           
        $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
        $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;
    /* ---- header location after session ----*/

    //Facebook Posting section---------------
    if($session) {
  try {
    $pageid = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;
    $response = (new FacebookRequest(
      $session, 'POST', '/$pageid/feed', array(
        'message' => 'text post on page!!'
      )
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject();

    echo "Posted with id: " . $response->getProperty('id');
  } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
    echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
    echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
  }   
}
  header("Location: index.php");
} else {
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
 header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
?>
```

Above source code

```
$pageid = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;
$response = (new FacebookRequest(
  $session, 'POST', '/$pageid/feed', array(
    'message' => 'text post on page!!'
  )
))->execute()->getGraphObject();
```

This is the main section of facebook posting.

Attached a posted content [image]

You can see posted message on notification area. I am surprised why this posting showing on notification section. I need to post message on page timeline.

Is there any other API to follow for page timeline posting or any setting on facebook page for showeing my posted message on timeline.

help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I got a solution.

We need to get Page Access Token. If you use page access token then facebook post on page timeline.


https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/